# not suceed in installing a self-built package using fpm

Tags: package-management

I am following [this example](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki/PackageMakeInstall) to build a deb file from the result of `configure/make/make install`, which succeeds. Then I used `fpm` to create a deb file:

```
# fpm -s dir -t deb -n nodejs -v 0.6.0 -C /tmp/installdir \
>   -p nodejs-VERSION_ARCH.deb \
>   -d "libssl0.9.8 (> 0)" \
>   -d "libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.3)" \
>   usr/bin usr/lib
Created package {:path=>"nodejs-0.6.0_i386.deb"}

# file nodejs-0.6.0_i386.deb 
nodejs-0.6.0_i386.deb: Debian binary package (format 2.0)
```

All looks fine, until I try to install from the new deb file [nodejs-0.6.0_i386.deb](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/nodejs-0.6.0_i386.deb):

```
# sudo dpkg -i nodejs-0.6.0_i386.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
(Reading database ... 1058122 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking nodejs (from nodejs-0.6.0_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nodejs:
 nodejs depends on libssl0.9.8 (>> 0); however:
  Package libssl0.9.8 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing nodejs (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nodejs
```

I already have `libssl1.0.0 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12` and `libstdc++6 4.6.3-1ubuntu5`.

They seem to satisfy `-d "libssl0.9.8 (> 0)"` and `-d "libstdc++6 (>= 4.4.3)"`.

What is the problem here?

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.