# What is the reason that configure file is required for uninstalling an application installed via configure, make and make install?

Tags: software-installation, make, configure, autotools

In https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141619/674

> I wouldn't store just the makefile. While the uninstall target may not
>   (or perhap, *should not*) need anything else to succeed, that's not a
>   guarantee.
>
> So that means keeping a copy of the original package.  There's not
>   much point, though, if there's a public archive of old versions and
>   you aren't worried about it going away.  You can just download it
>   again later anyway.  The only issue with this is that **for autotooled
>   stuff you need to run `./configure` first, and if you use different
>   options `uninstall` may miss something** -- but that's not such a big
>   worry, I think.  Occasionally I've kept notes about the particular
>   configuration of something.
>
> I keep independent source packages in `/usr/local/src`, but it as long
>   as you can find it when you need it, it doesn't matter.

Why is it that "for autotooled stuff you need to run `./configure` first, and if you use different options `uninstall` may miss something"?

What is the reason that the configure file is required for uninstalling an application installed via configure, make and make install?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose the package has an `--enable-foo` configure option that causes it to build its foo subsystem and install *libfoo.a* in …/lib and a *foo* executable in …/bin.  So you install that and clean up your temporary build directory.

You then come back months later, and unpack the package tarball afresh in order to uninstall it.  You need to rerun `./configure` to reconstruct the makefiles so that you can do `make uninstall`, and if you don't configure with `--enable-foo` then the commands to build/install/uninstall *libfoo.a* and *foo* may not be included in the respective make targets.  In which case, `make uninstall` would miss cleaning up *libfoo.a* and *foo*.

It would be worth preserving *config.status* from the original installation's build directory, as that records the configure options used.